# $a^2+b^3=c^5$Are there infinitely many solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am having troubles figuring whether there are infinitely many integer solutions to the following equation: $$a^2+b^3=c^5$$

This is just a problem I thought of on my own, so sorry in advance if this is already an open problem.

The way I tried to solve it is this:

We know that there are infinitely many integers such that $a^2+y^2=z^2$ . Therefore, if $b^3=y^2$ and $c^5=z^2$ , we might have a solution. This reduces to $y=b^{3/2}$ and $z=c^{5/2}$ . So $b$ and $c$ have to be squares. However, I don't know where to go from here. I don't know how to prove that there are infinitely many $y, z$ which satisfy $y=b^{3/2}$ and $z=c^{5/2}$ $and$ $a^2+y^2=z^2$ . Thanks.

Comment: one of your exponents is 2; nevertheless see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We will cheat. Let $a=2^{3k}$ and let $b=2^{2k}$. Then the left-hand side is equal to $2^{6k+1}$.

It is easy to find infinitely many $k$ such that $6k+1$ is divisible by $5$.

Just let $k$ be any integer congruent to $4$ or $9$ modulo $10$.

Then we can let $c=2^{(6k+1)/5}$.

**Remark:** We get into interesting territory when we ask that the numbers be relatively prime. For some information, see the Wikipedia article on [Beal's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal%27s_conjecture).

Comment: I love the cheat. :)

Comment: +1 Andre Nicolas, always the best :). By the way is it really supposed to be obvious that there are infinitely many solutions, like Anthony Peter said? I wouldn't think so, because $a^3+b^3=c^3$ is not bounded but it doesn't have any solutions.

Comment: (+1) But it's a perfectly fair answer; I don't get the "cheating" bit.

Comment: @JohnBentin I'm pretty sure it is "cheating" because normally the answer follows from manipulating the given data in the question- he (she?) hasn't shown how he got that answer, instead just saying that it is the right answer, with a proof.

Answer (score 7):

For solutions without common factor:

Beukers found polynomials such that $a=P(t), b=Q(t), c=R(t)$ is a primitive solution for all integer $t$, and Jonny Edwards gave a list of such polynomial curves that include all primitive solutions.

http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/dissertations/2006-0208-200155/appd.pdf

Solutions with common factors can be written down by elementary means such as selecting $n$ so that the three terms are equal to $2^n, 2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: For those curious, the 27 formulas for $x^2+y^3+z^5 = 0$ found by Beukers and Edwards are explicitly given by Alpern in this [website](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/SUMPOWER.HTM#P5_3_2).

Answer (score 4):

You can also get a solution from $a^2+b^3=d$, by multiplying by $d^{24}$:
$$(ad^{12})^2+(bd^8)^3=(d^5)^5$$