# $x^5 + y^2 = z^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

While waiting for my döner at lunch the other day, I noticed my order number was $343 = 7^3$ (surely not the total for that day), which reminded me of how $3^5 = 243$, so that $$7^3 = 3^5 + 100 = 3^5 + 10^2.$$
Naturally, I started wondering about nontrivial integer solutions to $$x^5 + y^2 = z^3 \tag{*}$$
("nontrivial" meaning $xyz \ne 0$). I did not make much progress, though apparently there are infinitely many solutions: this was Problem 1 on the 1991 Canadian Mathematical Olympiad. The official solutions (at the bottom of [this page](https://cms.math.ca/Competitions/CMO/)) only go back to 1994. A cheap answer is given by taking $x = 2^{2k}$ and $y = 2^{5k}$ so that the l.h.s. is $2^{10k + 1}$. This is a cube iff $10k + 1 \equiv 0 \,(3)$ i.e. $k \equiv 2\,(3)$ thus giving an arithmetic progression's worth of solutions, starting with $$(x, y, z) = (16, 1024, 128)$$ corresponding to $k = 2$ 
and $$(x, y, z) = (1024, 33554432, 131072)$$
coming from $k = 5$.

What else is known about the equation $(*)$? In particular, are there infinitely many solutions with $x$, $y$, $z$ relatively prime? The one that caught my attention was $(x, y, z) = (3, 10, 7)$. Another one is $(-1, 3, 2)$ because $-1 + 9 = 8$. By [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (now a theorem), this is the only solution with $x = \pm 1$ or $y = \pm 1$ or $z = 1$. Are there any solutions with $z = -1$? In this case, $(*)$ reduces to $x^5 + y^2 = -1$ and Mihăilescu's theorem does not apply.

**Update.** This question was essentially already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443915/a2b3-c5are-there-infinitely-many-solutions), since the equation $a^2 + b^3 = c^5$ is equivalent to  $(-c)^5 + a^2 = (-b)^3$.

Comment: we can rewrite this as $x^5+y^2\equiv 0 \pmod z$ could that help you ?

Comment: You might look at [OEIS sequences A070065](https://oeis.org/A070065), A070066 and A070067.

Comment: Note that if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, then so is $(c^6 x, c^{15} y, c^{10} z)$ for integers $c$.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-many-nontrivial-integer-solutions-exist-to-x-3-y-2-z-5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are infinitely many solutions. In fact, there are many parametrizations of the solutions.
According to a book${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$ on my bookshelf,

> Up to changing $y$ into $-y$, there are exactly 27 distinct parametrizations of the equations $x^5 + y^2 = z^3$.

One of the simplest paremetrization is given by following formula.

$$\begin{align}
x =&\; 12st(81s^{10}-1584t^5s^5-256t^{10})\\
y =&\; \pm (81s^{10} + 256t^{10})\\
&\;\;\times (6561s^{20} - 6088608t^5s^{15} - 207484416t^{10}s^{10} + 19243008t^{15}s^5 + 65536t^{20})\\
z =&\; 6561s^{20}+2659392t^{5}s^{15}+10243584t^{10}s^{10} - 8404992t^{15}s^5 + 65536t^{20}
\end{align}$$

For example, following two random choices of $s,t$ give you two sets of relative prime solutions.

- $(s,t) = (1,1) \leadsto (x,y,z) = (-21108,-65464918703,4570081)$
- $(s,t) = (1,2) \leadsto (x,y,z) = (-7506024,127602747389962225,-196120763999)$

The book I have is actually quoting result from a thesis${}^{\color{blue}{[2]}}$ by J. Edwards. Consult that if you really want to get into the details.

**References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ Henri Cohen,  *Number Theory Number Theory Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools*,
  $\S 14.5.2$ The Icosahedron Case $(2,3,5)$.
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ J. Edwards, *Platonic solids and solutions to* $x^2+y^3 = dz^r$, Thesis, Univ. Utrecht (2005).

Comment: Nice answer, especially for the first reference. +1

Comment: @achille: We can also use the icosahedral equation and scale it appropriately. Kindly see answer below.

Comment: @achille: The parameterizations for $x^5+y^3=z^2$ depend on the icosahedron while $x^4+y^3=z^2$ depend on the tetrahedron. Does the book you cite say how many distinct parameterizations are there for the latter? [This page](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/SUMPOWER.HTM#P4_3_2) gives $7$, but I just found an $8$th one, with no scaling involved.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII In $\S 14.4.1$ of that book, Cohen proved there are 7 parametrizations.

Comment: @achillehui: I just re-checked the parameterization I found, and it turns out there is a common factor. Darn! In [Edwards' work](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/7696/appd.pdf), he cites 7 parameterizations as well. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 9):

There is a beautiful connection between $a^5+b^3=c^2$ and the icosahedron. Consider the unscaled *[icosahedral equation](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0015)*,

$$\color{blue}{12^3u v(u^2 + 11 u v - v^2)^5}+(u^4 - 228 u^3 v + 494 u^2 v^2 + 228 u v^3 + v^4)^3  = (u^6 + 522 u^5 v - 10005 u^4 v^2 - 10005 u^2 v^4 - 522 u v^5 + v^6)^2\tag1$$

By scaling $u=12x^5$ and $v=12y^5$ (or various combinations thereof like $u=12^2x^5$, etc), we then get a relation of form,

$$12^5a^5+b^3=c^2$$

Comment: +1 interesting connection. it is unfortunate the mythical $j(\tau)$ is stuff way beyond me ;-p.