# On $17^7+76271^3=d^2$ and coprime solutions to $x^6+y^3=z^2$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373028/x5-y2-z3) got me curious. The Diophantine equation with $x\neq1$,

$$x^n+y^3 = z^2\tag1$$

has infinitely many coprime solutions when $n\leq5$. Are there at least [a few co-prime ones](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/SUMPOWER.HTM#P7_3_2) when $n>5$?

> $n=6:$ $\color{red}{??}$

No solutions with $x<100$ and $0<y<100000$. (I checked.)

> $n=7:$

$$2^7+17^3=71^2$$
$$17^7+76271^3=21063928^2$$

> $n=8:$

$$43^8+96222^3 = 30042907^2$$

> **Q:** Does $n=6$ in fact have a coprime solution? (It seems strange that $n=7,8$ has but $n=6$ doesn't. A larger search radius might yield a result.)

**P.S.:** From work by Darmon and Granville, if $1/p+1/q+1/r<1$, then the equation $ax^p+by^q+cz^r=0$ has only finitely many coprime solutions. So $(1)$ has only finitely many for $n\geq7$.

Comment: Considering only strictly positive integers first solutions to $x^6+y^3=z^2$ are $\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 8 & 24 \\
 3 & 18 & 81 \\
 4 & 32 & 192 \\
 5 & 50 & 375 \\
 6 & 72 & 648 \\
 7 & 98 & 1029 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proposition 14.6.1.** In the parabolic case $1/p + 1/q + 1/r = 1$, the equation $x^p + y^q = z^r$ has no solutions in nonzero coprime integers, except that the equation $x^3 + y^6 = z^2$ has the solutions $(x, y, z) = (2, ±1, ±3)$, and the equation $x^3 + y^2 = z^6$ has the solutions $(x, y, z) = (−2, ±3, ±1)$.

From Henri Cohen Number Theory Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools

Comment: Ah, I should have known. So that is what makes $n=6$ different from the $n=7,8$ cases since $1/6+1/3+1/2=1$.